# Best practice after user login

Tags: php, reactjs, react-router

I have a react login page, with everything that comes with it (lost password, verification of email, resend password etc). However I'm wondering what the "best practice" AFTER login should be.

My react component retrieves a "SUCCESS" after correctly entering username/password. But should I use react Router to direct my user to another location (and "enter" a new react-app handling things from here, or how would you guys/girls do this? I use php with react (axios). I thought of creating a session and the start a new react app (at another location) - which then checks to see if the session is valid or not. If it is ==> show secure things. If not ==> redirect to login page.

So my question is basically, which steps would you recommend, in order for my login/enterSite connection to work, as smooth as possible?

I haven't really tried anything yet, as I'm aiming for best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most web applications follow the following procedure:

Did the user come to login by some redirect or by clicking a login button?

If the user came from a login button click, keep the user on the same page or redirect to a profile page, based on app flow.

If the user came to login as a result of redirection, then redirect the user to the last page he wanted to visit or a component he was trying to access.

Comment: So what is best practice then for knowing that user is logged in, if at the same page (btn clicked)? Session/cookie (using php or react? Or a combo?)

Comment: My concern had more to do with “keeping track of user login” in a safe way (without being able to hack it at the front end” :) using php/react.

Comment: if you are using react then, you can store a flag and basic user info in redux or any other store. for PHP, session will do just fine.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I’ll go for a php (session/cookie) +redux store solution